# How To Extract the Plural only if only the plural is present, or the singular only if only the singular, or both if both are in Cell In Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula in `C2`:

```
=ifna(
transpose(
query(TRANSPOSE(iferror(
{REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(?)Fruits"),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(?)Fruit")})),"Select * where Col1<>'' ")),"")
```

And this formula in `C3`:

```
=ifna(
transpose(
query(TRANSPOSE(iferror(
{REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"(?)Fruits"),REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"(?)Fruit")})),"Select * where Col1<>'' ")),"")
```

And this formula in `C4`:

```
=ifna(
transpose(
query(TRANSPOSE(iferror(
{REGEXEXTRACT(A4,"(?)Fruits"),REGEXEXTRACT(A4,"(?)Fruit")})),"Select * where Col1<>'' ")),"")
```

Giving this output in range `A2:D4`:

| Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruits basket |  | Fruits | Fruit |
| Fruit juice |  | Fruit |  |
| Fruit juice and Fruits Basket |  | Fruits | Fruit |

How to get only the `Fruits` output in `C2` without the `Fruit` one in `D2`, while still getting the `Fruit` output in `C3`?

And still getting both `Fruits` output in `C4` with the `Fruit` one in `D4`?

Expected Output:

| Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruits basket |  | Fruits |  |
| Fruit juice |  | Fruit |  |
| Fruit juice and Fruits Basket |  | Fruits | Fruit |

I don't know what else to test.

I basically need the plural given value to be extracted without its singular duplicate if only the plural form is present in the cell as in `A2`.

And only the singular if only the singular in present in the cell as in `A3`.

And both singular and plural if both are present in the cell as in `A4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A slight adjustment to your current formula:*

```js
=ifna(
transpose(
query(TRANSPOSE(iferror(
{REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(?i)\bFruits\b"),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(?i)\bFruit\b")})),"Select * where Col1<>'' ")),"")
```

***Alternate formula to try***:

```js
=let(Σ,"Fruit",Λ," "&A2&" ",
     torow({if(iferror(search(" "&Σ&"s ",Λ)),Σ&"s",),if(iferror(search(" "&Σ&" ",Λ)),Σ,)},1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(?i)Fruits?","($0)"))
```

Comment: Thanks @z" for the alternative. I tested and it does work as per the expected output. Screenshot here: https://i.imgur.com/I0qQqak.png 
 The ArrayFormlua version: `=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"(?i)Fruits?","($0)")))`